# При проверке тега в GTM, Tag Assistant не соединяется с сайтом (not connect). Как правильно настроить теги/триггеры?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Возможно формулирую вопрос несколько сумбурно, потому что мало что понимаю в GTM. Действовал по [этой статье](https://vc.ru/marketing/172107-kak-sozdat-celi-konversii-v-novom-google-analytics-4), в настройках триггера "Условия активации триггера: Click Classes/Содержит/wpcf7-submit". В настройках тега "Тип: Google Аналитика событие GA 4/Идентификатор потока данных G-********" и выбран триггер. В форме на сайте кнопка отправки имеет код: `<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn" />`
Дальше выбираю предварительный просмотр, указываю адрес сайта, заполняю форму и полоска соединения в Tag Assistant доходит только до половины, а сверху слева видна надпись красным цветом "Not Connected". И никакого отчета о том что триггер/тег сработал, в итоге не вижу. Что я делаю не так, и как правильно настроить тег/триггер?

Answer (score 0):

Это значит что основной код ГТМ в HEAD не установлен или установлен неверно. Основной код ГТМ для установки на сайт можно найти при клике по номеру ГТМ.